# Changing a list of strings based on certain conditions

Tags: r, string

I have a string list here,

```
List <- c('C8 H12 O1 Na1', 'C15 H20 O7 Na1', 'C18 H24 O6', 'C24 H32 O9 Na1', 'C26 H38 O5 Na1')
```

And I would like to change it to

```
Listnew <- c('C8 H12 O1', 'C15 H20 O7', 'C18 H23 O6', 'C24 H32 O9', 'C26 H38 O5')
```

Where any string containing `Na` had it removed and any string that did not have `Na` had the `H` in the string reduced by 1. In this case, from `List`, `'C18 H24 O6'` was changed to `'C18 H23 O6'`. This list is contained in a matrix. I know how to changed strings based on one condition

I think that I need to create a True/False column on whether or not Na exists within the column's string first, then use that to either subtract '1' from the H string or remove the Na. However, I have tried to look for similar questions but I could not find an answer that worked for me.

Comment: You'll need to break down the strings into a matrix/dataframe, make the changes there, and then recreate the strings.

Answer (score 2):

With `sub` we can remove the `Na\\d+` at the end while subtracting 1 with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
new <- sub("\\sNa\\d+$", "", List)
i1 <- grep("\\bNa\\d+$", List, invert = TRUE)
new[i1] <- gsubfn("H\\d+", ~ paste0(substring(x,  1, 1),
    as.numeric(substring(x, 2))-1), new[i1])
new
#[1] "C8 H12 O1"  "C15 H20 O7" "C18 H23 O6" "C24 H32 O9" "C26 H38 O5"
```

---

or as @G. Grothendieck commented

```
new[i1] <- gsubfn("(H)(\\d+)", ~ paste0(x, as.numeric(y)-1), new[i1])
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear - just removing Na is easy, but my issue is with the second part of my question (reducing H by 1 if Na does not exist)

Comment: Suggest this minor simplification of the gsubfn line based on capturing the H
and digits separately avoding `substring` : 
`new[i1] <- gsubfn("(H)(\\d+)", ~ paste0(x, as.numeric(y)-1), new[i1])`

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be:

```
nums <- as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(List, '(?<=H)(\\d+)' ))-1
## subtracting every integer attached with H by 1
no_na <- grep('\\bNa\\d+\\b',List, invert = TRUE)
## picking the spot where Na is missing
replacement = unlist(lapply(no_na,function(x)gsub('(H)(\\d+)',paste0('\\1',nums[x]), List[x], perl = TRUE)))   
## replacing only that subtracted value which has no Na
List[no_na] <- replacement
## finally replacing using gsub Na followed by digit by ''
fout <- trimws(gsub('\\bNa\\d+\\b', '', List))
```

Output:

> ```
> > fout
> [1] "C8 H12 O1"  "C15 H20 O7" "C18 H23 O6" "C24 H32 O9"
> [5] "C26 H38 O5"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of the idea I suggested in the comment - we break down the strings, and then either remove the `Na1` or reduce the `H` by 1. Then we `paste` it all back together and return a vector.

```
sapply(strsplit(List," "), function(x) {if (any(grepl("Na",x))) {x[grepl("Na",x)]<-""} else 
                                {x[grepl("H",x)]<-paste0("H",readr::parse_number(x[grepl("H",x)])-1)}
                             return(trimws(paste(x,collapse=" ")))
                            })

[1] "C8 H12 O1"  "C15 H20 O7" "C18 H23 O6" "C24 H32 O9" "C26 H38 O5"
```

Comment: whoops, forgot the strsplit part... fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

With some `stringr` functions, test for the presence of `"\\bNa\\d+"`, extract the number after H, and decrease it.

```r
library(stringr)

List %>%
  ifelse(str_detect(., "\\bNa\\d+"), 
         .,
         str_replace(., "(?<=\\bH)\\d+", as.character(as.integer(str_extract(., "(?<=\\bH)(\\d+)")) - 1L))) %>%
  str_remove_all("\\bNa\\d+") %>%
  trimws()
#> [1] "C8 H12 O1"  "C15 H20 O7" "C18 H23 O6" "C24 H32 O9" "C26 H38 O5"
```

For a bit more legibility, pull the nested stuff out into a function.

```r
decrease_h <- function(x) {
  if (!str_detect(x, "\\bNa\\d+")) {
    n <- as.integer(str_extract(x, "(?<=\\bH)(\\d+)")) - 1L
    str_replace(x, "(?<=\\bH)\\d+", as.character(n))
  } else {
    x
  }
}

List %>%
  purrr::map_chr(decrease_h) %>% # or use sapply
  str_remove_all("\\bNa\\d+") %>%
  trimws()
```